# How to write protect a file in centos from root processes

Tags: linux, file, centos, file-permissions, selinux

I have few processes running from root user. This processes all try to edit a file named file.php. I need to lock the file that only one process can write on it at a time. Is there anyway to do that? maybe SELinux works?
I tried locking it using  flock but it didn't work! It was the code I used:

```
exec 3>file.php
flock -x 3
```

Comment: Use flock. https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock